# Other ways to close windows on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, window

Is there a way I can close windows by moving the border to the bottom of my screen? Just like in Windows 8, you see?

Thanks for the att.

Comment: What version are you using currently?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 LXDE (Lubuntu)

Comment: There is no really gui way to set this lubuntu. I think the only thing that making would be an openbox config.